# Assignment when reading line by line from file

Tags: c, glib

```
GSList* getWordList() {
    GSList *list;
    list = NULL;

    FILE *fh;
    fh = fopen("words.txt", "r");

    char *s;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&s, &len, fh)) != -1) {
        list = g_slist_append(list,s);
    }
    fclose(fh);
    return list;
}
```

So I have this code. I know that the issue is that 's' will always equal the last word I read. I'm struggling to figure out the solution for this.

`g_s_list_append` requires a GPointer passed to it, but I'm changing the value every iteration.

I'm extremely new to C, trying to crash course myself... What I'm thinking is I need to allocate memory for a new char * and set it equal to s and then give that to g_slist_append. Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've no idea what your question really is but... 1. Initialize `s` to null on it's decl. 2. Set `s` to null *again*, and len back to zero, on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `NULL` to `s` to avoid reading next word into the space previously allocated to `s`:

```
char *s = NULL; // Add initialization
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;

while ((read = getline(&s, &len, fh)) != -1) {
    list = g_slist_append(list, s);
    s = NULL; // Make sure that s's memory is not reused
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also explain how I can create a new pointer based on the value of another pointer? Basically, make a copy of it that doesn't point to the same memory address.

Comment: @Ben: consider using `strdup()` to duplicate the line that's read.  Be aware that `getline()` might well allocate 256 bytes for the line, and extend that if necessary, but if all your lines are 20 characters or less long, you could be wasting a lot of memory.  Also be aware that you are saving the newline in with the string that's part of your list.  If you don't want that, eliminate the newline before adding to the list (possibly before making the duplicate).  Note that the return value from `getline()` tells you where the newline is.

Comment: Since you're using glib, you should probably use `g_strdup` (and `g_free`) instead of `strdup` (and `free`). Also, it's much more efficient to *prepend* to the list (`g_slist_prepend`) then reverse it (`g_slist_reverse`); it saves a *lot* of list traversals.